# Get starttime or endtime from TStopWatch

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-2010

Is it possible to get (a TDateTime) starttime (or endtime) from a TStopWatch in Delphi 2010?

Clarification from comments: I do not need to account for multiple stop/restarts just want date & time that the stopwatch was started.

Comment: You should add the `delphi` tag to your delphi related question. (a 4k user should also know this)

Comment: What keeps you away from reading the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) and answer the question yourself? - It is simply, no you can't

Comment: You need to define your terms more clearly. What is the end time? When the `Stop` method was called? Or the time now? A stopwatch can be running or stopped. And the stopwatch can start multiple times. Which start time do you want?

Comment: @SirRufo, why couldn't you ? After stop is end time. Minus elapsed milliseconds is start time...

Comment: @TLama Stopwatch could have been paused. You can call `Stop; Start; Stop; Start;`

Comment: @SirRufo TStopWatch is hardly documented :(

Comment: TStopWatch is documented well enough to answer your question. I only need the declaration part to answer it. There is **no** public property with the starttime and David gave the point why. If you want to have a stopwatch just copypaste the source and build your own stopwatch record with some more public properties. It would be just a small bunch of code to implement.

Comment: Actually @SirRufo: It is NOT documented well enough because the Frequency property that DavidHeffernan is using in his answer is not documented, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Diagnostics.TStopwatch

Comment: Does the `TStopWatch` record has this property `Frequency` in Delphi2010? Do you not have the source for `TStopWatch`? And you asked how to get the start-time/end-time from `TStopWatch`. Simply you can't. The **calculation** of the start-time is only valid direct after stopping. But before calculating the start-time with the *maybe missing* frequency property just take the end-time by asking `Now` :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no property that will return the time at which the stopwatch started. So I think you'll have to do a little arithmetic to work this out.

- Divide `ElapsedTicks` by `Frequency` to obtain the number of seconds since the stop watch started.
- Subtract this value from the time now to obtain the time when the stop watch started.

The code might look like this:

```
uses
  Diagnostics, DateUtils;

function GetStopwatchStart(const Stopwatch: TStopwatch): TDateTime;
var
  ElapsedSeconds: Double;
begin
  ElapsedSeconds := Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
  Result := IncMillisecond(Now, -Round(ElapsedSeconds*1000));
end;
```

Note that this assumes that the stop watch is running, and has never been paused.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to simpy modify stopwatch start and stop methods to store current TDateTime using "now", than doing all that complex math.

Comment: @Silver Not if you are writing library code, say, and cannot modify rtl code. Or indeed have any other valid reason not to modify rtl code.

Comment: TStopWatch is declared in unit System.Diagnostics. Infact it is the only thing in that unit. So if you are afraid of making changes to this unit make a copy of it, made necessary changes and change the name of TStopWatch to let's say TModifiedStopWatch. This way you can make all neded changes without breaking original code.

Comment: @silver Feel free to do that if you wish. The question concerns TStopwatch.

Comment: Yes I understand that original question concerns TStopWatch itself. That is the reason why I haven't posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Silver I'd also question that the maths is complex. It seems simple enough to me. I agree that if you want to note a time, you can just call Now and remember the value. Presumably Remko is not in a position to do that. Perhaps the stopwatch is started by code outside his control.

Comment: Yes @DavidHeffernan is right: I have to interface some code with TStopWatch from Delphi 2010. Apart from the fact that I cannot distribute (modified) Delphi code: I do not have access to this particular Delphi version at the moment and documentation truely sucks.

Comment: Are you still stuck on this?